# Flutter notification and redirect page

Tags: flutter, notifications

I am developing a reminder app with flutter. I want to send a scheduled notification from the application and redirect it to the notification page when the incoming notification is clicked.

I tried this with flutter awesome. When I clicked on the notification, I was not successful in sending to the page.
[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71677117/flutter-open-page-on-click-notification/71680607#71680607)

Is there any way I can do this with another method?